# What does movsbl (%rax, %rcx, 1),%eax and $0xf, %eax do?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, gdb, x86-64

```
movsbl (%rax, %rcx, 1),%eax
and $0xf, %eax
```

I have:

```
%rax=93824992274748
%eax=1431693628
%rcx=0
```

I really don't know what the reason why I have these results:
How does the first instruction gives me `%eax=97`?
Why does the `and` between the binary representation of `97` and `1111` give me `1`?

Comment: The first instruction has a memory operand.  It loaded a byte with value 197 from address 93824992274748 and sign-extended into a 32 bit word.  The second instruction takes the bitwise and of that and `0xf` (or 15 in decimal), taking only the least-significant 4 bits of the value just loaded.

Comment: Oh no, the bomb again? :D As fuz said, the first instruction is a load from memory so you can't tell just from looking at the code what the result will be. If you debugged it and you got `97` then that's what was in memory at that address. Surely you know how bitwise `and` works, just write a `1` where both operands are `1`. `97 = 0110 0001b`, `15 = 0000 1111b` so the result is `0000 0001b`. It's keeping the last 4 bits. Given that is a hex digit, you can also do `97 = 0x61` and just keep the last digit which is again `0x01`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitwise AND compares the bits of both operands. In this case, 97 AND 15:

```
0110 0001  ;97
0000 1111  ;15
```

For each column of bits, if both bits in the column are 1, the resulting bit in that column is 1. Otherwise, it's zero.

```
0110 0001  ;97
0000 1111  ;15
---------------
0000 0001  ;1
```

You might be wondering what purpose this serves. There's a lot of things you can do with AND actually, many of which aren't obvious at first glance. It's very helpful to think of one of the operands as your data and the other as a "filter."

---

For example, let's say we have a function called `rand` that returns a random 32-bit unsigned integer in `%eax` every time you call it. Assume that all possible values are equally likely. Now, let's say that we have some function called `myEvent`, and whether we call it or not shall be based on the outcome of `rand`. If we want this event to have a 1 in 16 chance of occurring, we can do this:

```
call rand
and $0xf, %eax
jnz skip
   call myEvent
skip:
```

The reason this works is because every multiple of 16 has the bottom 4 bits clear. So those are the only bits we're interested in, and we can use `and $0xf, %eax` ignore everything to the left of those 4 bits, since they'll all turn into zeroes after the `and`. Once we've done the `and`, we can then see if `%eax` contains zero. If it does, `%eax` contained a multiple of 16 prior to the `and`.

---

Here's another example. This tells you if `%eax` is odd or even:

```
and $1, %eax
jnz isOdd
```

This works because a number is odd if its rightmost binary digit is 1. Any time you do a `n % 2` in a high-level language, the compiler replaces it with `n & 1` rather than doing actual division.